# How to Access the Nexus Repository using token?

Tags: ios, sonarqube, authorization, nexus

I am trying to access the Nexus repository as per my need. Please suggest me , how can i resolve the issue. Is there any other Basic authorization to achieve using token? using the Rest API Postmethod?

[image]

Thanks advance,

Comment: 403 forbidden means the account you're using does not have permissions to do what you need it to do.  Your question and title are otherwise unclear to me, so hope that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

on your `https://[nexus.url]/#admin/system/api` you can find all API.

for example use `curl -X GET  -u {my_token_login}:{my_token_password} "https://[nexus.url]/service/rest/v1/assets?repository=maven-releases" -H "accept: application/json"`  for seeing all artefacts in your maven-releases

Comment: hi. Thank you. Is there any other way to access the Nexus repository directly using url. i.e without curl

Comment: I am using the phone to access the nexus repository. pls suggest me . what i can do

Comment: choose between simple http url on browser or command line curl. is it a problem ?

Comment: for Http url on browser. we can give the credentials directly right. but my need  is , want to access the repository directly from the url in phone.. i don't want to use the command line curl. please suggest me. Is there any basic authorization to access ?

Comment: is there any api for authentication for nexus repository. like below request
POST api/permissions/add_user

Params      
 1. login = XXX

Comment: so tell us how you use your phone, how do you send the request, or use the API ? how do you get this result in screenshot ?

Comment: let me explain my issue.  i have saved my ipa files in nexus repository. now am trying to access the repository using the normal Alamofire request . but i didn't receive the  response as i expected. so i decided to send the username and password in the url. but it is easily accessible to anyone. right?

Comment: So i tried to authenticate the username and password in the form of basic authorization method. but it is not working. so i googled it. got the swagger UI . that SWagger UI screenshot i have posted above.

Comment: is there any authentication to access the nexus rest Api?

Comment: the swagger UI on your nexus repository ? for accessing this you re already login, no ?

Comment: i haven't logged in.

Comment: there is no login url and authorization token.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213237/discussion-between-maxence-lecointe-and-newbieios).

Comment: You can authenticate with tokens if you are running the nexus pro version: https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/security/security-setup-with-user-tokens

Comment: the above url seems not found.